# How to add a Package to kernel to make it default package?

Tags: package-management, kernel, software-installation, xclip

I want to add xclip package to kernel to make it default package. Means if I give mine custom version of kernel to someone to install then xclip package should also be installed with kernel. They don't have to use "apt-get install xclip" command to get it. How is it done?

Answer (score 0):

You'd add `xclip` as `Depends` in the package headers. How you best do that largely depends on *how* you're packaging the kernel.

If you're building from the Ubuntu packages, the `debian/control` file currently contains:

```
Depends: ${misc:Depends}, binutils, bzip2, coreutils | fileutils (>= 4.0)
```

Just add `xclip` onto the end:

```
Depends: ${misc:Depends}, binutils, bzip2, coreutils | fileutils (>= 4.0), xclip
```

---

If you're building out another way, it might just be easier to add the dependency after the fact. A package is just a compressed archive. You can still break in and edit the `control` file after something has been packaged but you'll need to resign it (if you're signing).